# Why am I losing these bits while defining structs in unions

Tags: c, struct, bit-shift, unions

I have the following problem, I am assigning a number of bits within structures that are in a union.I trying to recombine them with a separate structure in that same union. However, when I assign mvUpper in Individual I lose that data or a significant bit based on the value I am assigning in Individual.(Please note I only lose data upon the portions I recombine in notIndividual) Please disregard the name, this was my investigation of unions before implementation.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
typedef union testing
{   
    struct Individual
    {  
    unsigned short mt  : 10;
    unsigned short mlbl : 3;
    unsigned short mvUpper :3;
    unsigned short mvLower :3;
    unsigned short mlUpper :2;
    unsigned short mlLower :5;
    }Individual;
    struct bE
    {
        unsigned int woo: 26;
    }bE;

    struct notIndividual
    {  
    unsigned short mt  : 10;
    unsigned short mlbl : 3;
    unsigned short mv :6 ;
    unsigned short ml : 7;
    }notIndividual;
} testing;


int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
    testing dothis;

    memset(&dothis,0,(sizeof(dothis)));

    printf("THIS IS THE SIZE of union%lu\n",sizeof(dothis));

    //printf("SIZE %d",sizeof(dothis.Individual));
    //printf("NOT SIZE %d",sizeof(dothis.notIndividual));

    dothis.Individual.mvUpper=3;

    printf("Testing MT%u\n",dothis.Individual.mt);
    printf("Testing MLBL %u\n",dothis.Individual.mlbl);
    printf("Testing MVUpper %u\n",dothis.Individual.mvUpper);
    printf("Testing MVLower %u\n",dothis.Individual.mvLower);
    printf("Testing ML Upper %u\n",dothis.Individual.mlUpper);
    printf("Testing ML Lower %u\n",dothis.Individual.mlLower);


    printf("Testing Mt %u\n",dothis.notIndividual.mt);
    printf("Testing Mlbl %u\n",dothis.notIndividual.mlbl);
    printf("Testing MV %u \n",dothis.notIndividual.mv);
    printf("Testing ML %u\n",dothis.notIndividual.ml);
    
    printf("THIS IS THE WORD %u\n", dothis.bE.woo>>21);


    return 1;
}
```

This is the output I can't understand

```
THIS IS THE SIZE of union4
Testing MT0
Testing MLBL 0
Testing MVUpper 3
Testing MVLower 0
Testing ML Upper 0
Testing ML Lower 0
Testing Mt 0
Testing Mlbl 0
Testing MV 0 
Testing ML 0
THIS IS THE WORD 0
```

I was trying to test out an easy way of bit-shifting through unions.

Comment: unsigned short is 16bits in length. mvUpper is the highest 3 bits on a 16bit value. In the notIndividual struct, you are again asking for 16bit shorts. mt + mlbl sums to 13bits. mv + ml will end up being in the next 16bit value (because 13 + 6 == 19, which is bigger than 16!). Your value is hiding in the 3bits between mlbl and mv.

Comment: Most of the behaviour of bit-fields is left as 'implementation defined' by the C standard.  Anything you find out with one compiler may not apply to any other compiler on the same platform — or to other compilers on other platforms.  You should print the value in `dothis.bE.woo` in hex without any shifting to see what value is stored in it.  That will reveal why you get zero when it _is_ shifted.

Comment: Note that the correct format specifier for `size_t` values (such as the value returned by `sizeof`) is `%zu`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To preface, the organization of bitfields within a struct is implementation defined, so you can't reliably depend on a certain layout.  That being said, here's what it most likely happening.

The base type for each of your bitfields is `unsigned short`.  So the compiler will try to group each of the bitfields into units of that size.

For the first struct, the layout is as follows:

```
struct Individual
{  
unsigned short mt  : 10;     // 10 bits used in unit 0
unsigned short mlbl : 3;     // 13 bits used in unit 0
unsigned short mvUpper :3;   // 16 bits used in unit 0
unsigned short mvLower :3;   // 3 bits used in unit 1
unsigned short mlUpper :2;   // 5 bits used in unit 1
unsigned short mlLower :5;   // 10 bits used in unit 1
}Individual;
```

And the second:

```
struct notIndividual
{  
unsigned short mt  : 10;   // 10 bits used in unit 0
unsigned short mlbl : 3;   // 13 bits used in unit 0
unsigned short mv :6 ;     // 6 bits used in unit 1 (not enough in unit 0)
unsigned short ml : 7;     // 13 bits used in unit 1
}notIndividual;
```

If you change all of your bitfields to have base type `unsigned int`, the bitfields will be more packed and you'll get the result you expect.

Comment: Thank you so much! In retrospect, that makes sense!